# WorldWind Image at Elevation

Tags: java, worldwind

Is there a way to put an image in WorldWind at elevation?  I'm able to use a [Surface Image](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/2.0/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/render/SurfaceImage.html) to place an image on the globe -- but I'd like to have it instead at a given elevation above the terrain, but I'm not finding it in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an image on a `Polygon` and place it at any elevation you want. Take a look at `gov.nasa.worldwind.examples.Polygons`. The relevant lines are:

```
ArrayList<Position> pathLocations = new ArrayList<Position>();
pathLocations.add(Position.fromDegrees(28, -110, 5e4));
pathLocations.add(Position.fromDegrees(35, -108, 5e4));
pathLocations.add(Position.fromDegrees(35, -111, 5e4));
pathLocations.add(Position.fromDegrees(28, -111, 5e4));
pathLocations.add(Position.fromDegrees(28, -110, 5e4));
pgon = new Polygon(pathLocations);
pgon.setValue(AVKey.DISPLAY_NAME, "Has an image");
normalAttributes = new BasicShapeAttributes(normalAttributes);
normalAttributes.setDrawInterior(true);
normalAttributes.setInteriorMaterial(Material.WHITE);
normalAttributes.setInteriorOpacity(1);
pgon.setAttributes(normalAttributes);
pgon.setHighlightAttributes(highlightAttributes);
float[] texCoords = new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0};
pgon.setTextureImageSource("images/32x32-icon-nasa.png", texCoords, 5);
```

Comment: Will this stretch the image to the size of the polygon like the sector does for SurfaceImage?

Comment: If you use the `texCoords` from the above example it will stretch the image to the four corners of the polygon.